# Problema al abrir la cámara en aplicación Android

Tags: java, android, cámara

Un botón que al ser presionado abrirá la cámara del terminal a través de un `intent` , hará una foto y la guardará en un directorio, esto último desde la aplicación.

Mi problema surge a la hora de abrir la cámara, no consigo abrirla y obtengo el siguiente error al presionar el botón que debería abrirla:

> E/Cámara: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/imagen.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Aquí os dejo el código de mi aplicación:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.FileUriExposedException;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
    private Uri imageUri;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

    public void hacerFoto(View view) {

        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "imagen.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al abrir la cámara:"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Log.e("Cámara ", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PICTURE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    try {
                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                                .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="asier.dam2.camaraandroid.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Hacer foto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="hacerFoto" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Permisos que añado en AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Estas usando Android N???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este error [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html) es generado en [Android N](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html):

> android.os.[FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html):
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/imagen.jpg exposed beyond app through
>   ClipData.Item.getUri()

Puedes realizar un cambio al obtener la Uri del archivo mediante:

```
imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
```

Este sería el cambio en código:

```
...
...
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "imagen.jpg");
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "imagen.jpg";
        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
        //imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

        //Validación de acuerdo al OS.            
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
              imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
        } else{
               imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
        }

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

       try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al abrir la cámara:"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Log.e("Cámara ", e.toString());
        }
...
...
```

---

Otra solución es cambiar el **targetSdkVersion** a una versión menor a 24 (Android N)

Comment: ¿Estoy equivocado o eso también significaría que la aplicación no corre en Android 24+ ? Generalmente sería mejor de dejar targetSdkVersion en la mas reciente y discriminar por anotación que método se usa, o no?

Comment: Se tiene maxSdkVersion que determina cual es la mayor API que puede soportar la aplicación, pero si no se incluye, por default se determina que puede trabajar en todas no importando el targetSdkVersion. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: En un futuro, en algún momento tendría que cambiar a el targetSdkVersion 24 o posteriores. Pero una solución rápida para evitar el Bug es la segunda que propongo. Lo ideal es validar el código como la primera opción para que funcione en todas (⌐■_■)

Answer (score 2):

Desde API 24 ya no es posible de compartir `URI` en `Intent`. El problema esta causado por:

```
       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
```

Para solucionarlo tienes que usar un proveedor:

```
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),"com.your.package.fileProvider", newFile);
```

[Pregunta en stackoverflow en ingles sobre el tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

[Documentación sobre `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Comment: Hola amigo Stefan, me parece que el problema es como se obtiene la Uri en Android N, ahora debe ser con Uri.parse();  =|