# Reporte Crash android.os.FileUriExposedException en Android N

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Con la actualización de la google play console me aparecen los informes de error.

Por lo visto solo afecta a la versión de Android 7 (Android N)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4525)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4568)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1706)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: 
  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9510)
  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9468)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1525)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4389)
  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4348)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4672)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4640)
  at pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity.openTrackKML(DetailedActivity.java:592)
  at pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(DetailedActivity.java:563)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7404)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7230)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4521)
```

Buscando más información de [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html)

La excepción salta cuando abro un fichero `.kml` con una aplicación externa a mi app, es decir mediante un intent.

```
private void openTrackKML() {
    try {
        String fileName = myItem.getTrackURI();
                /*int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
                if (pos > 0) {
                    fileName = fileName.substring(0, pos);
                }*/

        //int idTrackResource = this.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" +fileName,"id",this.getPackageName());

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = FileDirUtils.readFileFromAssets(this, fileName);
        FileDirUtils.saveExternalFile(byteArrayOutputStream, "temp_track.kml");

        Log.d(TAG, "id Track Rresource: " + String.valueOf(fileName));

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp_track.kml");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
        startActivity(intent);

                /*//Open by url
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(myItem.getTrackURI());
                Log.d(TAG, "action_gotrack click()" + uri.toString());
                if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(uri.toString())) {
                    //startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
                }*/
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(), getString(R.string.detailed_warning_install_kml_viewer), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }

}
```

Los permisos de escritura, también los pido en runtime

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="false" />
```

Probando en el emulador, porque no dispongo de dispositivo Android N me devuelve

```
  android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/temp_track.kml exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
      at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
      at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8933)
      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
      at pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity.openTrackKML(DetailedActivity.java:592)
      at pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity.processActionOption(DetailedActivity.java:504)
      at pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity.access$000(DetailedActivity.java:57)
      at pro.caminsderonda.app.caminsderonda.DetailedActivity$1.onClick(DetailedActivity.java:109)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Este SO puede ser la clave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Mas detalle en https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este error [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html) es generado como ya has explicado en [Android N](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html):

Ahora hay que realizar un cambio al obtener la `Uri` del archivo mediante:

```
imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
```

ejemplo:

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
              imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
        } else{
               imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
        }
```

---

En tu código sería :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {                
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "temp_track.kml"), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");        
} else{
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "temp_track.kml"), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
}
```

---

Otra solución es cambiar el **targetSdkVersion** a una versión menor a 24 (Android N)

Es similar a el problema que se tiene en esta pregunta:

[Problema al abrir la cámara en aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44937/problema-al-abrir-la-c%C3%A1mara-en-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/44967#44967)

Answer (score 0):

Este problema se me presentó en Abril de 2020 y la respuesta de @Jorgesys funcionó perfectamente, esto es lo único que tuve que hacer:

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, filename);
Uri path = Uri.FromFile(file); //Cambiar esta línea por la siguiente
Uri path = Uri.Parse(file.ToString());
```