# Tomar Imágen desde Cámara y mostrarla en Image View

Tags: android, cámara

Necesito tomar una foto con la cámara y mostrarla en el `ImageView`, pero me salta un error en el `Uri`, al parecer es en el `Uri.fromFile()`.

**¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?**

Este es mi código:

```
public class AddArticle extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int COD_FOTO = 20;

private static final String CARPETA_PRINCIPAL = "Hipack/";
private static final String CARPETA_IMAGEN = "HipackImages";
private static final String DIRECTORIO_IMAGEN = CARPETA_PRINCIPAL + CARPETA_IMAGEN;
private String path;
File fileImagen;
Bitmap bitmap;

private ImageView imgProducto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_article);
    setTitle("Agregar Artículo");

    imgProducto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageProductoAddA);
}


public void tomarFoto(View vista){
    File miFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DIRECTORIO_IMAGEN);
    boolean isCreada = miFile.exists();
    String nombreImagen = "";

    if (!isCreada){
        isCreada = miFile.mkdirs();
    } if (isCreada){
        nombreImagen = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) + ".jpg";
    }

        fileImagen = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), nombreImagen + ".jpg");

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fileImagen)); // Aqui me da el error
        startActivityForResult(intent, COD_FOTO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case COD_FOTO:
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("Ruta de almacenamiento", "Path: "+path);
                        }
                    });
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            imgProducto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Éste es el error que me salta:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.humberto.hipackpro2, PID: 31387
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
               Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/1537456175.jpg.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1962)
                  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
                  at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:942)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9850)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9835)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1612)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4514)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
                  at com.example.humberto.hipackpro2.AddArticle.tomarFoto(AddArticle.java:206) //Aqui me manda a la línea del código
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Buen día Humberto podrías poner el log para poder entender mejor el problema saludos

Comment: @Serna Listo, he agregado el error que me salta ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisa el error que se esta provocando en el `LogCat`:

> Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/1537456175.jpg.jpg exposed beyond app
>   through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Si estas creando el archivo con extensión, no necesitas agregarle nuevamente una extensión cuando creas el archivo, realiza este cambio:

```
...
...
   if (!isCreada){
        isCreada = miFile.mkdirs();
    } if (isCreada){
        nombreImagen = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) + ".jpg";
    }

      //Error  fileImagen = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), nombreImagen + ".jpg");

  fileImagen = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), nombreImagen);
...
...
```

---

Otro detalle importante relacionado a el error `FileUriExposedException` es que realices esta validación ya tu aplicación funcionaría para dispositivos con Android 8.0 o posteriores pero no para versiones de sistema operativo anteriores, realiza este cambio:

```
...
...
     Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  

    Uri imageUri;
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
              imageUri = Uri.parse(fileImagen);
        } else{
               imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileImagen));
     }

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri /*Uri.fromFile(fileImagen)*/); 
        startActivityForResult(intent, COD_FOTO);
...
...
```

Revisa esta respuesta relacionado a el error `FileUriExposedException` :

[Reporte Crash android.os.FileUriExposedException en Android N](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71443/reporte-crash-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-en-android-n)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que al usar MediaScannerConnection el listener se llamara de forma asincronica y nunca tendras el path correcto cuando haces decodeFile ya que estan corriendo en hilos de ejecucion distintos.
Aca te dejo una forma de hacerlo sincronico para que no te ocurran esos problemas.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case COD_FOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                imgProducto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el consejo pero me sigue marcando el error si no me equivoco en el Uri antes de entrar al onActivityResult() ¿Podrias hecharle un vistazo?

Comment: Ya veo, si tu targetSdkVersion es mayor a 24 vas a tener que usar un provider por cuestiones de seguridad. Deberas agregar un provider_paths.xml. En el manifest agregar el <provider> que apunte a ese xml y en el codigo cambiar Uri.fromFile() por FileProvider.getUriForFile(). Te dejo un link para que veas el ejemplo de codigo.
https://medium.com/@sauge16/targetting-sdkversion-24-android-nougat-and-above-and-sharing-file-through-intent-3f0f0128fa7e

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto la manera en la que lo puedes solucionar:

```
File file = new File("Nombre de tu path");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();

        // Con las siguientes 2 lines se soluciona la excepción
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, COD_FOTO);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```