# ¿Cómo soluciono el error Android.OS.FileUriExposedException en Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.Android en la que genero un PDF con iText7.
El PDF aparentemente se está creando bien, pero al terminar de crearlo quiero abrirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Esto en realidad está al principio, solo lo pongo para que vean la ruta del pdf
directory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/Prueba";
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "Prueba.pdf");

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
Intent verPDF = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
verPDF.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "application/pdf");
verPDF.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
StartActivity(verPDF);
```

El problema es que cuando hace el `StartActivity(verPDF)` me sale la siguiente excepción:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details

Estuve googleando el error pero no encuentro algún caso parecido en el que quieran abrir un archivo...

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora desde la liberación de Android 7 debes realizar un cambio:

[Reporte Crash android.os.FileUriExposedException en Android N](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71443/reporte-crash-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-en-android-n)

En lugar de:

[Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.net.uri.fromfile?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)

debes usar:

[Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.net.uri.parse?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)

ejemplo:

```
verPDF.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file), "application/pdf");
```

---

Abrir .pdf mediante Intent, Ejemplo:

```
public void OpenPdf(string filePath)
{
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///" + filePath);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    try
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "No hay aplicación disponible para abrir el PDF.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema que tengo ahora es que no puedo abrir el PDF... la App no da ninguna excepción, pero cuando quiero abrirlo el mismo lector de PDF me devuelve el mensaje: "No se pudo acceder al archivo. Compruebe la ubicación e intente de nuevo"

Comment: Imprime la dirección almacenada en la variable "directory", y revisa si en realidad existe en tu dispositivo.

Comment: La variable directory tiene esto: `/storage/emulated/0/Prueba`, después creo la variable `path` que queda así: `/storage/emulated/0/Prueba/Prueba.pdf` y para el `StartActivity()` hice esto: `if (file.Exists()) { StartActivity(verPDF); }` y está entrando, por lo que el archivo aparentemente existe... ahora, si entro por USB a mi dispositivo, nunca encuentro la ruta