# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial in Android App using nagition fragment component

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estaba desarrollando una App en Android en Java, en la que necesito acceder a la camara del dispositivo para realizar una foto, la cual después pretendo guardar en una BBDD local, y mostrarla en un ImageView.
El tema esq tras buscar documentación en internet implemente la apertura de la camara como vi en diferentes foros, que no la documentacion oficial, asi que seguramente al ser un errror de seguridad, supongo que debería ceñirme más a a la documentacion oficial.

Asi que después de solucionar bastantes errores he llegado a este el cual no se como solucionar:

Logcat.

```
2021-04-21 12:35:39.927 516-516/com.example.journal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.journal, PID: 516
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://media/external/images/media/24} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{b9000cd 516:com.example.journal/u0a133} (pid=516, uid=10133) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3851)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1705)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:584)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:236)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:218)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$3.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:219)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.launchStartActivityForResult(FragmentManager.java:2926)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1403)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1377)
        at com.example.journal.ui.capture.CaptureFragment.dispatchTakePictureIntent(CaptureFragment.java:320)
        at com.example.journal.ui.capture.CaptureFragment.access$100(CaptureFragment.java:56)
        at com.example.journal.ui.capture.CaptureFragment$1.onClick(CaptureFragment.java:128)
```

Este sería el fragmento donde invoco la camará:

FragmentCapture.fragment

```
public class CaptureFragment extends Fragment {

    private CaptureViewModel mViewModel;
    private ImageButton btnCamara;
    private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO = 0 /*1*/;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private Uri photoURI;
    private EditText Ettitulo;


    /***** TODO: Solucionar NullPointer en el onClick del boton, ya que no invoca antes los métodos para guardar la imagen******/

    public static CaptureFragment newInstance() {
        return new CaptureFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_capture, container, false);

        Ettitulo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EtInstantanea);

        //Create the inicial ImageView until the user take a photo, which is an Icon.
        //Drawable inicialView = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.bird);

        mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgCapture);
        if(mPhotoImageView != null){
            mPhotoImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.bird));
        }

        btnCamara = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

//        if(btnCamara!=null){
            btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    //1.Open the camera.

                    if (v == btnCamara) {

                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        225);
                            }


                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                        226);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //Guarado de la foto en el almacenamiento interno
                            dispatchTakePictureIntent();

                        }
                    }

                    //2. Recover the photo and write into internal storage.
                    //TODO: Use AlerrtDiolog para solicitar nombre de la foto.
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    String titulo = Ettitulo.getText().toString();

                                    // keep into DB.

                                    Birddb bd = Birddb.getDatabase(getContext());

                                    //Contructor con el titulo introducido por el usuario, y la url de la foto.

                                    bd.birdDAO().insertBird(new BirdRoom(titulo, mCurrentPhotoPath));


                                    //Send the Jornal,

                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("edtValue", titulo);
                                    bundle.putString("image", mCurrentPhotoPath);

                                    //Swicth the () -> fragment
                                    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
                                    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                                    JournalFragment jf = JournalFragment.newInstance();
                                    jf.setArguments(bundle);
                                    transaction.replace(container.getId(),jf);
                                    transaction.commit();

                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    //No button clicked

                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foto NO añadida a su diario personal.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

                    Intent intento1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File foto = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    intento1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(foto));
                    startActivity(intento1);

                    //3. Set the photo into the ImageView,
                    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+Ettitulo.getText().toString());

                    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap1);

                    mPhotoImageView.setImageDrawable(d);

                    //4. Ask if the user want to keep that pjoto into his jornal.

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder1.setMessage("¿Le gustaría guardar esta foto en su diario?");
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);

                    builder1.setPositiveButton(
                            "Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    //Instancio la BBDD local..
                                    Birddb db = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(),
                                            Birddb.class, "database-name").build();


                                    //Añado el objeto Bird a la BBDD local.
                                    BirdDAO birdDAO = db.birdDAO();
                                    //List<Bird> users = userDao.getAll();
                                    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            //Guardar Objeto Bird en la BBDD.


                                            String descripcion = Ettitulo.getText().toString();
                                            BirdRoom bird = new BirdRoom(descripcion, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                                            Birddb.getDatabase(getContext()).birdDAO().insertBird(bird);
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ejemplar añadido correctamente a su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });

                    builder1.setNegativeButton(
                            "No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha añadido la foto actual a su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();

                }
            });
        //}


        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CaptureViewModel.class);

    }

    private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        225);
            }
        }if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted CAMERA.");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        226);
            }
        }

    }




// GUARDADO DE LA FOTO EN EL DISPOSITIVO FÍSICO.
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                photoURI = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                // Send to the Adapter of the RecycleView to draw.
                Bundle datos = new Bundle();
                datos.putString("uri", String.valueOf(photoURI));



                //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);




            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    /***************AQUI ES DONDE SE PONE EL IMAGEVIEW A PARTIR DE LA FOTO TOMADA POR LA CÁMARA.**************/

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Si teneís idea de por donde van los tiros, muchas gracias de ante mano!

[EDIT]

Añado el manifest y la camara debería lanzarse al invocar el método dispatchTakePictureIntent()

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.journal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bird"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Journal">
        <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".FirtsScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[EDIT]

Tras aplicar los cambios, he conseguido que se habra la camara del dispositivo para tomar la foto, pero al tomarla , la App crasea mostrando el siguiente error:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.journal/files/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.journal/files/Pictures/JPEG_20210421_172023_3916131699507863577.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:963)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10249)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10234)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4652)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:584)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4610)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:570)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4971)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentHostCallback.java:166)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1344)
    at com.example.journal.ui.capture.CaptureFragment$1.onClick(CaptureFragment.java:191)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6619)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6596)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25932)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

[EDIT]

Tras aplicar los cambios ahora el error se da en el intent que se encarga de almacenar la foto en el dispositivo, lanzando el siguiente error:

```
[17:20, 21/04/2021] Manuel Lucas: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.journal/files/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.journal/files/Pictures/JPEG_20210421_172023_3916131699507863577.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:963)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10249)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10234)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4652)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:584)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4610)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:570)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4971)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentHostCallback.java:166)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1344)
    at com.example.journal.ui.capture.CaptureFragment$1.onClick(CaptureFragment.java:191)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6619)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6596)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25932)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
[17:37, 21/04/2021] Manuel Lucas: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.journal/files/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.journal/files/Pictures/JPEG_20210421_173312_4847409018428011875.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:963)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10249)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10234)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4652)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:584)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4610)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:570)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4971)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentHostCallback.java:166)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1344)
    at com.example.journal.ui.capture.CaptureFragment$1.onClick(CaptureFragment.java:191)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6619)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6596)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25932)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

[EDIT]

He añadido al intent que lanza la actividad de la camara los sioguientes flags, según decian varios foros, aunque sigue dando el mismo error:

```
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Muéstranos el como lanzas o inicias la cámara y el manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí se define el problema:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
> act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3
> cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity
> clip={text/uri-list U:content://media/external/images/media/24} (has
> extras) } from ProcessRecord{b9000cd 516:com.example.journal/u0a133}
> (pid=516, uid=10133) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Se necesitan permisos para el uso de la cámara.

Al ser [el permiso android.permission.CAMERA un permiso definido como "Peligroso"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=es-419#CAMERA) además de declararlo en el `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**es demasiado importante realizar también la petición manual de este permiso y este permiso debe ser aceptado por el usuario**, el mensaje de error indica que fue revocado o no fue aceptado.

Lo puedes verificar en la configuración > Apps y seleccionas tu aplicación, en la sección permisos deberías tener activado el permiso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Con respecto a el error:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException

Es imporante realizar el cambio indicado en esta respuesta:
[Reporte Crash android.os.FileUriExposedException en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/71447/95)

Despues de Android 7.0 (nivel de API 24) debes usar `Uri.parse(...)` en lugar de `Uri.fromFile(...)` por lo que debes realizar la siguiente validación:

```
       Uri imageUri = null;

       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
              imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
        } else{
               imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
        }


Intent intento1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File foto = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), mCurrentPhotoPath);
intento1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivity(intento1);
```

Comment: Como puedes ver en el codigo el permiso de la camara esta añadido en manifest

Comment: Hola @ManuelLucas si, pero el permiso debe ser aceptado por el usuario ya que el mensaje de error indica que fue revocado, puedes revisar en los settings de la aplicación y veras que no esta activado.

Comment: Y como veo los settings de la aplicación?? |@Jorgesys

Comment: @ManuelLucas agregue una imagen, ve a settings o configuración es un "engrane" ahí buscas "apps" o "aplicaciones" y busca tu app, revisa sus permisos.

Comment: Sabes @ManuelLucas estaba viendo que podrías llamar checkExternalStoragePermission() en onCreateView además de que al dar clic al boton "btneCamara" también revisa los permisos.

Comment: Lo he proobado y efectivamente salta la camara y te permite hacer una foto, pero al hacerla obtengo el siguiente error: android.os.FileUriExposedException:

Comment: Ese es otro error diferente, agregué en la respuesta como solucionar ese punto @ManuelLucas

Comment: Si, pero no llego a entender a que te refieres con lo de la imagen..

Comment: En mi menu de settings no esta la opcionde 'Apps'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123237/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-manuel-lucas).