# ¿Cómo puedo abrir un PDF desde la carpeta assets en la app por defecto de Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, pdf

Estoy intentando abrir un documento PDF ya introducido en la carpeta assets de mi proyecto. Este debe abrirse en el lector de por defecto de Android. Antes he conseguido hacerlo mediante una librería externa, pero lo que hace esta librería es abrirlo desde su propio lector, lo que yo necesito es que se abra en el lector de por defecto de Android. Este es el código que tengo de la librería:

```
/**
 * Función que recibe el nombre del pdf y busca en la carpeta assets para cargarlo
 */
private fun showPdfFromAssets(pdfName: String) {
    pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
        .password(null) // if password protected, then write password
        .defaultPage(0) // set the default page to open
        .onPageError { page, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error at page: $page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        .load()
}
```

No tengo más código para conseguirlo y he investigado por ahí pero solo he encontrado código deprecated en Java. Gracias de antemano.

Esta es la otra función que he hecho

```
    private fun copyAssets() {
    val assetManager = assets
    var files: Array<String>? = null
    var pdfName = "cons.pdf"
    var filePath = "file://" + filesDir + "/"

    try {
        files = assetManager.list(filePath + pdfName)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e)
    }

    if (files != null) for (filename in files) {
        var `in`: InputStream? = null
        var out: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            `in` = assetManager.open(filename)
            val outFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename)
            out = FileOutputStream(outFile)
            copyFile(`in`, out)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: $filename", e)
        } finally {
            if (`in` != null) {
                try {
                    `in`.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.message.toString())
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.message.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    val miUri: Uri

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        miUri = Uri.parse(filePath + pdfName)
    } else{
        miUri = Uri.fromFile(File(filePath + pdfName))
    }

    intent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.setDataAndType(miUri, "application/pdf")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Y este es el error al completo que me da

```
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.example.pdf/files/cons.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1960)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9885)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9839)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.copyAssets(MainActivity.kt:95)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:36)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$tGt1fi2HeFZw7d_eZTjofohhZ5w(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder abrir el archivo, necesitas copiar el archivo desde assets hacía el directorio de almacenamiento interno, desde ahí se podrá abrir sin problema usando un intent.

```
   private void CopyReadPDFFromAssets(archivo: String){
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), archivo);
            try{
                in = assetManager.open(archivo);
                out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("CopyReadPDFFromAssets", e.getMessage());
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            String filepath = "file://" + getFilesDir() + "/" + archivo;
            Uri myUri = null;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
               myUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
            } else{
               myUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
            }


            intent.setDataAndType(myUri,
                    "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
```

Suponiendo que tu archivo .pdf se llama "archivo.pdf"  llamarías el método de esta forma:

```
CopyReadPDFFromAssets("archivo.pdf")
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Con la función CopyReadFromAssets, me da un error justo en la línea donde dice "startActivity(intent)" de tipo FileUriExposedException. Según estoy viendo, este error se produce porque el fragmento que incluye "Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE" está deprecated y si intentas usarlo salta el error (aunque esta línea está dentro del try-catch). Al menos, en Kotlin sí me está dando este error, en Java creo que también ocurre lo mismo. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Para versiones posteriores a Nougat se usar Uri.parse(), para anteriores Uri.fromFile(), tu sistema operativo en el móvil es algo "antiguo", actualice el código, el error se debe a esto: [Reporte Crash android.os.FileUriExposedException en Android N](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71443/reporte-crash-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-en-android-n)

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error y también se produce el error en el try-catch, en la línea "out = openFileOutput(file.name, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)" porque MODE_WORLD_READABLE está deprecated. De hecho lo pone tal que así en la documentación: "Precaución: Los modos MODE_WORLD_READABLE y MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE se dieron de baja desde el nivel de API 17. A partir de Android 7.0 (API nivel 24), Android arroja un SecurityException si los usas." Actualmente uso en el emulador la API 27.

Comment: En lugar de usar Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE he probado a usar Context.MODE_PRIVATE, ahí no da error en el try catch y lo hace completo, pero me vuelve a dar el mismo error en la línea del startActivity(intent).

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta, veo que usas Kotlin, agregaré ambas versiones Java y Kotlin,..

Comment: Hola, ¿editaste el código? Es que no sé si me falla a mí esto pero no veo cambios, ya me ha pasado otras veces. Gracias.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta principal para añadir otra función que he hecho, pero me sigue dando el mismo error en startActivity(intent)

Comment: No ha editado nada y me ha dejado tirado.